# how to use ngFor to fetch two array

Tags: angular

I'm new in Angular2. I want to fetch two array in a **li** like bellow:

[array1] in [array2]

for example, I have two array, the first for Names and second for Ages and I want to have an output like this:
***name in age***

and also I know that it's possible to use a 2D array for this but I don't want.
I would like to know which is it possible by ngFor?

it's my Angular code:

```
@Component({
    selector:'peaple',
    template: `
        <h2>{{title}}</h2>
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="#name of names">
                {{name}} in {{ages}} age
            </li>
        </ul>
        `
})
export class PeapleComponent{
    title = "Example";
    Names =["N1","N2","N3"];
    Ages=["20","15","37"];
}
```

and I want a result like this (but without changing in arrays format)

N1 in 20 age

N2 in 15 age

N3 in 37 age

Comment: Can you put your arrays here? Thanks!

Comment: Could you please give a concrete example of what you would like? It's very unclear to me right now.

Comment: Yes, but since that code isn't valid code, we can only guess what it's supposed to do. What should be the result? What HTML do you want to generate? My guess is that you want to do what Pierre Urban's answer shows, but maybe it's not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
  <ul>
       <li *ngFor="let i of Names; let k = index">
       {{i}} in {{Ages[k]}} age
       </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks more as a data modeling problem to me.

I would suggest you to merge both arrays into one with the following person interface:

```
{ name: string, age: number }
```

So your array would have a type of person[]. Then in your template you can use the structural directive *ngFor as follow:

```
<li *ngFor="let person of array">
  {{person.name}} is {{person.age}} year old
</li>
```

Comment: If you really want to keep both arrays, then you can use the index from *ngFor="let name of names; let i = index", then {{name}} in {{age[i]}} age.